# What does Ketil mean by "trusting someone" in season 2 episode 18 of Vinland Saga?

Tags: vinland-saga

20 minutes into S2E18 of *Vinland Saga*, what does Ketil mean by

> "What does it mean to trust someone? It's true? It's real? I won't suffer losing something I never doubted" as he beats Arnheid, and we see flashbacks of him and the woman he once loved when he was young.

Is this a poor translation?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga. I tried to edit the title to make it clear while still avoiding the spoiler. I hope the edit is okay for you. Otherwise, feel free to [edit] further. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Not sure of your question. It means quite literally what it says. He thinks he was betrayed by Arnheid and there's no such thing as trust.